# if f is a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ that can be written $f = E + O$ where E is an even function...

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-explanation

if f is a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ that can be written $f = E + O$ where E is an even function and O an odd function, prove that writing $f$ in this way is unique.

Sol'n:

A solution that I read suggested:  $$ f(x) = E(x) + O(x) \\f(-x) = E(x) - O(x)$$

What I do not understand is how does this illustrate that the function is unique?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve the equations for $E$ and $O$ in terms of $f$:

$$\begin{align*}
E(x)&=\frac12\big(f(x)+f(-x)\big)\\
O(x)&=\frac12\big(f(x)-f(-x)\big)
\end{align*}$$

for each $x\in\Bbb R$. Thus, $E$ and $O$ are completely determined by the function $f$.

Comment: So uniqueness is established because E and O are completely determined by our one function $f$. But what was the idea behind using both $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$?

Comment: @dc3rd: Expressing $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ in terms of $E$ and $O$ gives you a pair of equations easily solved for $E(x)$ and $O(x)$. You have $f(x)=E(x)+O(x)$ automatically, and if you look around for some $y$ such that $f(y)$ can also be expressed in terms of $E(x)$ and $O(x)$ (so that you can solve for $E(x)$ and $O(x)$), $y=-x$ is the only reasonable thing to try.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm going to phrase this properly but I will try. What gives you the "license" to be able to introduce the $y = -x$ idea? I get why you would do it after thinking about it, but I would have rejected doing something like that because I would've felt that I violated the parameters of the question because it was not something given to me within the question.

Comment: @dc3rd: It is given to you in the question: it just isn’t given explicitly. That is, any time you talk about a real number $x$, you can certainly also talk about the real number $-x$. And in any context involving odd and even functions it’s very likely that you will *want* to talk about $-x$ as well as $x$. More generally, if you’re interested in some arbitrary $x\in\Bbb R$, and in the context at hand it turns out to be useful to look at $-x$, or at $2x$, or at $\sin\pi x$, there’s absolutely nothing stopping you. You use whatever tool is available and useful.

Comment: going to remember that. thanks for the assistance

Comment: @dc3rd: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f(x)=E_1(x)+O_1(x)=E_2(x)+O_2(x)$, with the $E_i$ even and the $O_i$ odd ($i=1,2$). Then
$$ E_1(x)-E_2(x)=O_2(x)-O_1(x)$$

The left-hand side is even, and the right-hand side is odd. But the only function which is both even and odd is the zero function.

Comment: Now I attempted something like this originally and I came the the same sort of conclusion, but I was not sure how this could establish uniqueness.

Comment: It shows that $E_1(x)=E_2(x)$ and $O_1(x)=O_2(x)$, which is exactly the statement that the decomposition is unique.

Comment: Ah! I see. By the fact that the only function which is both even and odd being 0 means we can set each of the expression to be equal to zero and voila.